# Inner join on multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I've a list of airline tickets.
For every ticket I've Departure, Arrival, Destination and Return expressed as airport IATA codes (JFK, LAX, DFW...).
I need to apply to the ticket the airport city and country that I've stored in another table to all 4 columns to have something like Departure_City, Departure_Country, Arrival_City, Arrival_Country and so on.

I tried with multiple inner join like:

```
SELECT        biglietti.Agenzia, biglietti.CodiceCompagnia, biglietti.TipoBiglietto, biglietti.CodiceBiglietto, biglietti.StatoBiglietto, biglietti.SerieBiglietto, biglietti.StatoEmissione, biglietti.TipoViaggio, biglietti.CodicePersonale, 
                         biglietti.TipoTratta, biglietti.ClasseVettore, biglietti.MastroCliente, biglietti.SottocCliente, biglietti.DataEmissione, biglietti.DataVariazione, biglietti.DataPartenza, biglietti.DaLocalita, biglietti.ALocalita, 
                         biglietti.ImponibileVettore, biglietti.StatoBolla, biglietti.NumeroBolla, biglietti.DataBolla, biglietti.TasseAerop, biglietti.ImpCorrispettivi, biglietti.CorrispettiviAdd, biglietti.CategoriaBene, biglietti.Sezionale, 
                         biglietti.ScontoCommissioni, biglietti.PercScontoComm, biglietti.NumeroPax, biglietti.Destinazione, biglietti.DataRimborsoFat, biglietti.StatoFattura, biglietti.ImpVetComp, biglietti.NonCommComp, 
                         biglietti.PercCommAct, biglietti.ImportoComm, biglietti.ImportoCommPass, biglietti.NumeroBiglietto, biglietti.PenaleVettore, biglietti.PenaleNonComm, biglietti.NomePasseggero, biglietti.NumeroBiglCong, 
                         biglietti.NumeroFattPass, biglietti.AccontiPass, biglietti.TasseYQ, biglietti.TasseYR, biglietti.CodicePnr, biglietti.Mese_Emissione, biglietti.Anno_Emissione, biglietti.Fare, biglietti.Nome_Mese_Emissione, 
                         biglietti.Quarter, biglietti.Partenza, biglietti.Arrivo, biglietti.DestinazioneFinale, biglietti.Ritorno, CASE WHEN Arrivo = DestinazioneFinale THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS SegPari, biglietti.Prop, biglietti.AnnoFiscale, 
                         compagnie.Descrizione AS NomeCompagnia, compagnie.Categoria, compagnie.Alleanza, aeroportip.Città AS CittàPartenza, aeroportip.Paese AS PaesePartenza, aeroportip.Latitudine AS LatPartenza, 
                         aeroportip.Longitudine AS LongPartenza, aeroportip.Timezone, aeroportia.Città AS CittàArrivo, aeroportia.Paese AS PaeseArrivo, aeroportia.Latitudine AS LatArrivo, aeroportia.Longitudine AS LongArrivo, 
                         aeroportia.Timezone AS TzArrivo, aeroportid.Città AS CittàDest, aeroportid.Paese AS PaeseDest, aeroportid.Latitudine AS LatDest, aeroportid.Longitudine AS LongDest, aeroportid.Timezone AS TzDest, 
                         aeroportir.Città AS CittàRit, aeroportir.Paese AS PaeseRit, aeroportir.Latitudine AS LatRit, aeroportir.Longitudine AS LongRit, aeroportir.Timezone AS TzRit, 
                         CASE WHEN aeroportia.Paese = 'United States' THEN 'NAT' WHEN aeroportia.Paese = 'Messico' THEN 'NAT' WHEN aeroportia.Paese = 'Canada' THEN 'NAT' ELSE 'ROW' END AS Pillar
FROM            dbo.Biglietti AS biglietti INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Compagnie AS compagnie ON biglietti.CodiceCompagnia = compagnie.Codice INNER JOIN
                         dbo.AeroportiOpenData AS aeroportip ON biglietti.Partenza = aeroportip.IATA INNER JOIN
                         dbo.AeroportiOpenData AS aeroportia ON biglietti.Arrivo = aeroportia.IATA INNER JOIN
                         dbo.AeroportiOpenData AS aeroportid ON biglietti.DestinazioneFinale = aeroportid.IATA INNER JOIN
                         dbo.AeroportiOpenData AS aeroportir ON biglietti.Ritorno = aeroportir.IATA
WHERE        (biglietti.DataEmissione >= DATEADD(year, - 2, GETDATE()))
```

However, after 10/02/2016 the query begins to write always the same ticket...so no luck!

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong or I may do better?

Comment: Your query seems OK to me, but the problem is not very clear.

Comment: Have you tried checking your data at Biglietti?

Comment: Is this in a Development environment? Do all of the rows after a certain date not have the 4 columns filled out that you are joining to? If so, joining to a Null or Default value may return a default row on the AeroportiOpenData table, like a 0 row.

Comment: Just to debug, I'd add a where clause for a specific ticket# and move the where clause after each join and then run it; to see where the cardinality join problem is.

Comment: If i remove the inner joins beyond CodiceCompagnia everything is fine...uhm...anyway the problem starts at line 301

Comment: Probably your JOIN is not very well implemented. First of all, if you're selecting "ALL THE STUFF" and if that means "ALL THE STUFF FROM ALL TABLES JOINED", the JOIN will return a cross table if the other JOINS is wrong... Try to check your JOIN and what you want to select. Without the results and without the columns you want, is hard to help

Comment: I put the whole query :)

Comment: Well then look at the first join after CodiceCompagnia and see what is not matching.  Start by making it a left join.

Comment: _"...query begins to write always the same ticket"_ - this query is designed to return multiple rows and does not write anything. Please clarify what you mean.

Comment: I mean that if i execute it at some point it begins to repeat always the same row

Comment: @Bass, What is a "repeat"? Serially requesting for a single-row resultset you are receiving same ticket as a first row? This query returns different rows but same ticket is duplicated several times in same resultset?

Comment: It means that when i run that query i get a correct list until the 10-02-2016. After that time period it repeats the same row over and over